# JavaCC: I wish to generate java classes from dynamically generated jj files and to compile them at runtime

Tags: java, runtime, javacc

I am refactoring a project which uses javaCC to create a proprietary language parser during compile time. Due to the fact that different variations of languages can exist at the same time, it has been decided to dynamically generate the java source code from the jj files during runtime, to then compile the java files into class files and load them.

In order to do so more efficiently I would like to generate the java files in memory to some stream I suppose. JavaCC's API Javadoc is not too accessible :).

How best to progress?

Comment: JavaCC is open source, so its API is very accessible. However, I'm going to strongly suggest that you do not do this, because it's going to become a maintenance nightmare. Instead, change your build process to separately build and package the variants of your language (which is itself very questionable from a maintenance standpoint)

Comment: The language is in part derived from an xsd schema file. Initially there had been only one. At the time of writing there are already five and that is expected to grow. That is why I we wish to automate the process of language parser generation.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off amending your build process as kdgregory suggests. But, [this article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/malenkov/archive/2008/12/how_to_compile.html) describes how to create a new class loader that compiles bits of Java code on the fly using the compiler API. It should be fairly easy to modify it to read from files rather than strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Compiler API aka JSR-199 (see [`javax.tools`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html)) to compile in memory generated classes. You'll need to extend `javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject` class to create a class that will represent the source text of a Java class in RAM.

Check out the following [example](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/snippet/iframe/TestJavaCompiler.java.html), it has an implementation of a `RAMResidentJavaFileObject` that is actually doing that.